# Unable to explode my list in json to separate rows or columns

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, dataframe

```
"assignees": [{
                "id": 1234,
                "username": "xyz",
                "name": "XYZ",
                "state": "active",
                "avatar_url": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "web_url": "bbbbbbbbbbb"
            },
            {
                "id": 5678,
                "username": "abcd",
                "name": "ABCD",
                "state": "active",
                "avatar_url": "hhhhhhhhhhh",
                "web_url": "mmmmmmmmm"
            }
        ],
```

I have this column in my JSON file. This column repeats several times, containing different values.
I want to split this column into separate columns like:
id   username  name  state  URL

basically like excel columns with respective values. But whenever I am trying to use the function: `df.explode('assignees')`

It is showing me the error:

```
ValueError: columns must be unique
```

Similarly, I have a column

```
"labels": [
            "Scanning",
            "Scanning at Scale",
            "Workflow"
        ],
```

The same error is showing for this. Labels are also occurring a lot of times with different values in my JSON file. I want the labels to be in row format, repeating. Like:

```
Scanning
Scanning at scale 
Workflow
Scanning
Scanning at Scale
Workflow
Priority
Firewall
```

In this manner I want. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you have a json/dict that looks like this:

```
json = {"assignees": [{ "id": 1234, "username": "xyz", "name": "XYZ", "state": "active", "avatar_url": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "web_url": "bbbbbbbbbbb" }, 
                     { "id": 5678, "username": "abcd", "name": "ABCD", "state": "active", "avatar_url": "hhhhhhhhhhh", "web_url": "mmmmmmmmm" }]}
```

If that is the case you could just use `pd.DataFrame(json.get('assignees'))` to create a DataFrame of this format (which is what you want as far as I understand):

|  | id | username | name | state | avatar_url | web_url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1234 | xyz | XYZ | active | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | bbbbbbbbbbb |
| 1 | 5678 | abcd | ABCD | active | hhhhhhhhhhh | mmmmmmmmm |

Comment: Could you please tell me for labels?

Comment: Do I have to use explode function after : pd.DataFrame(json.get('assignees')) ?

Comment: Why is it not working for me ToT

Comment: Hi. I tried your method, but only one of them got split. The other part did not.

Comment: Please give some more concrete information. My answer is specific to your first question, you didn't mention labels before. 
I am not sure if .explode() is the right approach here, as your data structure is not 100% clear to me. do you have a label value for each row ? 
Could you give an overview over all columns you need and/or the structure of your json file?

Comment: Yeah actually I tried loading the file through json.load() instead of reading it, and then applied json.get and explode, so it's working fine for now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I have tried reading the json from a url, and stored it into dataFrame, but now the explode function is not working for me. I used pd.DataFrame(df.get('assignees')    df.explode('assignees')

Comment: Could you help me out, please?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution with separate and order data is using pandas library, bellow you can get your data in DataFrame type, and you can also rearrange it to save it as JSON again:

```
import pandas as pd
jtry={"assignees": [{ "id": 1234, "username": "xyz", "name": "XYZ", "state": 
"active", "avatar_url": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "web_url": "bbbbbbbbbbb" }, { "id": 
5678, "username": "abcd", "name": "ABCD", "state": "active", "avatar_url": 
"hhhhhhhhhhh", "web_url": "mmmmmmmmm" }]}
jtry['assignees'][0]
df_jtry=pd.DataFrame(jtry['assignees'])
print(df_jtry)
```

and remake as dict() to load it as JSON again:

```
new_dic={'id':list(df_jtry['id'].values),'username':list(df_jtry['username'].values),'name':list(df_jtry['name'].values),'state':list(df_jtry['state'].values),'avatar_url':list(df_jtry['avatar_url'].values),'web_url':list(df_jtry['web_url'].values)}
```

Comment: Actually I can't load back to json because I am calling it through Url. Could you provide me some other solution please. I am badly stuck T⚬T

Comment: ok if you load it from a URL so it is owned by another one and you can not edit it... right?
so what would you like to do?

Comment: I am reading the json from URL and then storing it into dataframe, and then applying explode function on assignees column (which is a list of dictionaries), but the list is opening and dictionary is not, even if I am normalizing it.